# PnP PowerShell to get all lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, pnp-powershell

I have a question regarding the PnP Powershell and the usage.

So basically, I've created a simple foreach to iterate all subwebs to print a detail froma list. But it does not work as supposed. It doesn't do anything.

```
$webs = Get-PnPSubWebs -recurse -IncludeRootWeb -Includes "Lists";

    foreach($web in $webs)
    {
        foreach ($item in web.Lists["MyCustomList"].Items)
        {
            write-host $item.Title;
        }
      }
```

I've tried to reproduce everything step by step in the Powershell Window:

1. Ok it gives me all webs with lists (firstly I didn't know I had to order lists to be included)

   $webs = Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse -IncludeRootWeb -Includes "Lists"
2. This shows me all the lists

   $webs.Lists
3. But I'm stuck here:

   $web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyCustomList")

This returns nothing! I've tried GetById and everything but it doens't work. I could only get a list like this: `$web.Lists[20]` (with index)

Could you please assist, so that I can interate through webs, find my list and iterate through all the items in my list. (this is for sharepoint 2016)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you will need to get the list object itself using `Get-PnPList`

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplist?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint CSOM APIs are currently not supported in PnP PowerShell. You cannot use [`ListCollection.GetByTitle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee545815(v=office.15)) method in PnP PowerShell.

You can use Get-PnPListItem for a known list in your site:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteUrl = "<SiteURL>"
$Username = "<Domain\user>"
$Password = "<Password>"
$ListName = "<ListName>"

#Connect to PNP Online
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credential $cred

#sharepoint online pnp powershell get list items
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "Title"
 
#Loop through each Item
foreach($ListItem in $ListItems) { 
    Write-Host "Title:" $ListItem["Title"]
}
```

Reference: [SharePoint Online: Get All List Items using PowerShell Script.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/09/sharepoint-online-get-list-items-using-powershell.html)